# Reading seismic data sets in SU and SEGY formats

Tags: stream, fortran, disk

My question is about speed comparison for reading seismic data from random location on disk when data formats are different.

In one case  I have SU (seismic unix) formatted data which I read in fortran with access='direct'.
In the other data set I have the same file converted to SEGY format.   I have to read this one with access='stream' as record size is not fixed on segy data sets.

Trace locations I read from are very  random in both cases. Data length  for traces is about 10 kilobytes.

I am observing speed ratio of about four between the two data sets (ie reading modes)
Is this expected.  If not what could be wrong?

Comment: This seems fairly domain specific - you probably will get more responses in a forum focused on dealing with seismic data. Sorry, I can't suggest one to you.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. I fear you would have to show us the code and explain the format. Remember, this is a general coding site. In the fortran tag questions usually contain some actual Fortran code. See also [ask] for more.